# How to convert dictionary list?

Tags: python, json

I have a list and I would like to turn it into json. but I get the following error:

```
trackerror:list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

and

```
The 'operation' tag of the JSON file is not correct or does not exist
```

What could it be?.

Observation:

```
list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

It is generated in this line: `url = variables["url"]`

I have:

```
event=
[[{'operacion': 'generar','url':'xxxxxxxx', 'items': [{'unidad': 'un', codigo'001'}]
}]]
```

I need (json):

```
event=
{ 
   "operacion":"generar",
   "url":"xxxxxxxx,"
   "items":[ 
      { 
         "unidad_de_medida":"un",
         "codigo":"001"
      }
   ]
}
```

Code:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    payload=json.dumps(event,indent=4) 
    variables= json.loads(payload)
    url =variables["url"] --------->>>>I have an error here too.<<<<<<<-----------
    headers={'content-type': "application/json",'authorization': "xxxxxxxx",'cache-`enter code here`control': "no-cache",'postman-token': "xxxxxxxx"}     
    response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

The webservice response indicates that it does not exist.

Comment: All you have to do is to extract the dict from your nested list.  This is `event[0][0]`, I believe.

Comment: Can you share a little more about the context of your program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
event=[[{'operacion': 'generar','url':'xxxxxxxx', 'items': [{'unidad': 'un', 'codigo':'001'}]}]]                                                                                    

json.dumps(event[0][0])

# '{"operacion": "generar", "url": "xxxxxxxx", "items": [{"unidad": "un", "codigo": "001"}]}'
```

Comment: Hi, I tried it, but it doesn't work.payload=json.dumps(event,indent=4)

Comment: You need to use event[0][0] like @oppressionslayer did, or use a loop like what I did if you're expecting multiple events. Also your dictionary entry for `codigo` has formatting errors in your original post

Answer (score 0):

PS: Your dictionary key `codigo` is formatted incorrectly. If this is not simply a typo when making this post, you will need to fix this before any processing can be done. However, since Python would throw an error, I'm guessing it's just a formatting error in your post?

Your `event` list is one level too deep to make any sense. Based on your desired output description, you could do this:

```py
event = [
    [
        {'operacion': 'generar','url':'xxxxxxxx', 'items': [
                {'unidad': 'un', 'codigo': '001'}
            ]
        }
    ]
]

extractedEvents = []
for e in event:
    extractedEvents.append(e[0])

print(extractedEvents)
```

1. It's a bit easier to see what you're dealing with if you take the time to format the original source similar to what I've done.
2. By traversing into the redundant list index with `e[0]` we're flattening the object by one level, like you indicated you wanted

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, if it is a mistake to write, the json is very big for it. Now the dictionary is smaller it seems to me, but as I pass it to JSON.

now:
event = [
        {'operation': 'generate', 'url': 'xxxxxxxx', 'items': [
                {'unit': 'a', 'code': '001'}
            ]
        }
    ]
I need:
event =
{
   "operation": "generate",
   "url": "xxxxxxxx,"
   "items": [
      {
         "unit_of_measurement": "a",
         "code": "001"
      }
   ]
}

Comment: Yep, my bad, I was assuming your event object had the potential to have many entries. So in my code, because `extractedEvents` is a list, you would need to grab the first element by `extractedEvents[0]`. In reality though, just go with the solution from @oppressionslayer above if you are confident that you will only ever have one event.